# Escape space char in win batch command

Tags: batch-file

I have this:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe\ logcat -d -v raw ^| find "BBTests" ^| more') do ( 
  @echo %%a
)
```

How can I escape the space in "program files"? I've tried:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ("""c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe\"" logcat -d -v raw ^| find "BBTests" ^| more") do (
```

but %%a captures the for loop line text instead of logcat command output.

If I set that path as an env, then running the below works:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a in ('adb logcat -d -v raw ^| find "BBTests" ^| more') do (
```

Comment: did you notice the difference in quoting between the working and the non-working line?  `... in ('"path with spaces\program.exe" parameters ^|find "something"') do ...` (Btw: use a single backslash only as path delimiter)

Comment: @Compo it works, please write a response so I can accept it

Comment: @Stephan I saw it, the first one that does not work has the same quotation as the last one which works...the middle one was an example of what I've already tried

Comment: @Stephan, in this particular situation your suggestion would not work, because the command in between `(`/`)` behind `in` is executed by `cmd /C`, which removed the outer-most quotes, leaving behind the invalid command line `path with spaces\program.exe" parameters ^| find "something`; as soon as you add an additional pair of surrounding quotes, you supply quotes to be removed by `cmd`; when you escape these additional quotes (`^"`) you do not even have to alter any other escaping…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you would do it like this:

```bsh
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^""%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat -d -v raw ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" "BBTests" ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com"^"') Do @Echo %%G
```

Or if you prefer not to use the `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` variable:

```bsh
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^""C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" logcat -d -v raw ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" "BBTests" ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com"^"') Do @Echo %%G
```